# How to extract date from a python string

Tags: python, date, python-dateutil

I want to extract a `date` from a `string` using python's [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package. The `date` comes in different formats, but the `day` part of the `date` is not present in any one of these `string`.

`Month` when written in Alphabets preceeds `year` like `Sep 2016`, but while written as numeric succeeds `year` like `2016-09` or `201609`

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
print(dparser.parse("The file is for month Sep 2016.",fuzzy=True).month)
   9
print(dparser.parse("The file is for month Sept-2016.",fuzzy=True).month)
   9
print(dparser.parse("The file is for month 2016-09.",fuzzy=True).month)
   9
```

How to deal with the case when there is no hyphen `-` between `year` and `month` as shown below -

```
print(dparser.parse("The file is for month 201609.",fuzzy=True).month)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-566e083c8313> in <module>()
----> 1 dparser.parse("The file is for month 201609.",fuzzy=True).month

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1180         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1181     else:
-> 1182         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1183 
   1184
```

Is there an option inside this library to do so?

Answer (score 0):

A completely different solution if you don't mind using a external package is to use dateparser (https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) which can parse dates in multiple formats (even includes some NLP features)

Otherwise you can use regular expression to extract this date format (e.g. '[0-9]{6}') and then separate the year from the month. This only works if the year precedes the month.

Comment: Can you provide examples demonstrating that it works with `dateparser`?

Comment: you can use the module: from `dateparser.search import search_dates` then pass your strings to `search_dates` along with the desirable settings  (e.g. `search_dates("The file is for month Sept-2016.", settings={"PREFER_DAY_OF_MONTH": "first"})`  `PREFER_DAY_OF_MONTH` is set to first because the day is missing and dateparser will always return a full date.

Comment: Well, problem is with format like 2016-09 or 201609. It doesn’t work for that.